# SharePoint send an email to users specified in a Field

Tags: email, sharepoint, field, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint list of Issues and have set a column (called Alert) to a “Person or Group” (allowing multiple names).

I would like the system to send an email to all the users listed in the Alert field, if the respective Issue is modified.

How do I set the Workflow to send an email the users as specified by the data in the Alert field (if there is any)? I know how to use the Workflow etc – the problem the “To” part of the Workflow's email.

(Sorry if this item has already been tackled – I've searched Stack Overflow and Googled around but could not find an answer)

Preferably through SharePoint Designer. i.e. preferably with no Code.

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have limited experience with SP Designer workflows, but have you tried the email action with "Workflow Lookup" selected in the To field?  This allows you to use specific fields from the submitted list item.

Comment: great this is what I was loking for saved me hours!!

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the SPUtility.SentEmail method which will send an email to the string you pass it from using the context of the SharePoint server, saving you from writing the code youself to send it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer – I'm looking for a solution to be done preferably through SharePoint Designer. I.E. preferably with no Code (sorry if it was not clear in my question).

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Build Dynamic String" workflow action to compose the list of email addresses. You can then use the dynamic string variable in the TO field. You can find the variable under  "Workflow Data" in the lookup dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the SPD workflows can only send to a person field that allows single selections.  If you need to send an email to multiple users you will have to find a custom action (similar to http://www.codeplex.com/SPDActivities) or develop a Windows Workflow Foundation workflow using Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a workaround to make the workflow send emails to multiple users entered under the field type `Person/Group`:

1. Create a workflow variable with type `String`
2. Assign the variable to `Current Item field name` and return type `String`
3. Then send an email To: `Variable Name`